# Display Ad in website From Revive Ad Server

Tags: openx, advertisement-server

I have installed Revive Ad server on my server. I have created advertiser, banners, campaign, websites, zones and liked banners and finally I generated invocation code in javascript. 
This is the invocation code for a 300*50 sized banner::

```
      <script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
            var m3_u =         (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://republica.bajratechnologies.com/revive/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://republica.bajratechnologies.com/revive/www/delivery/ajs.php');
      var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
      if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
      document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
      document.write ("?zoneid=1&amp;withtext=1");
      document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
      if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
      document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
      document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
      if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
      if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
      if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
     document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
  //]]>--></script><noscript><a href='http://republica.bajratechnologies.com/revive/www/delivery/ck.php?n=ad68e8df&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://republica.bajratechnologies.com/revive/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=ad68e8df' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>
```

I have included this tag in my website, but it displays nothing. I removed noscript tag and again run the code, but nothing change occurred. I inserted random number 123 on INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE section, nothing is displayed in this case too.

How to display ad in website using this invocation code?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your browser has ad block turned on. If you turn it off, it should display.